# Creating app for old mac from new mac machine?

Tags: c, gcc, osx-leopard

I am writing an sample app on MAC OSX 10.6 having gcc version 4.2. 
I am compiling app using gcc version 4.2 . 
It is working fine on the same machine but on MAC OSX 10.5 (gcc 4.0) it is not working. 
how can I compile it on 10.6 so it will also work on old machine ?

I am getting these error

```
dyld: unknown required load command 0x80000022
Trace/BPT trap
```

command I used to build is

```
gcc -m32 main.cc
```

Comment: Are you compiling by hand or through an IDE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-arch i386 -Wl,-macosx_version_min,10.5` will help; I don't know for certain if they'll be sufficient, though.

Comment: If that produces warnings, the OP needs to post them so that we can tackle any issues.

Comment: @Rafe 
I am getting 
dyld: unknown required load command 0x80000022
Trace/BPT trap

Comment: Is that with or without the `-Wl` option above?  Without it, the linker will indeed use load commands that 10.5 won't understand; the above `-Wl` option should force it to use load commands understood by 10.5.

Comment: @geekosaur when I tried your command I am getting invalid arch name x86

Comment: *sigh* some things want x86, some want i386, I half expect something somewhere in 10.6 expects ia32...  Try `-arch i386` instead.

Comment: with i386 I got ld: symbol dyld_stub_binding_helper not defined (usually in crt1.o/dylib1.o/bundle1.o)
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Answer (score 2):

The application was incorrectly built on OS X 10.6 machine for a 10.5 machine. The developer can fix this by considering three things:

```
Using the correct compiler parameters:
gcc-4.2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.5 -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk ...

Using the correct linker settings (setting environment variable before link command). This is required, so that the OS X 10.6 linker will not use the loader command 'LC_DYLD_INFO_ONLY' (=0x80000022), because OS X 10.5 does not understand this command:

export MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.5
(or   setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.5)
```

After this is fixed, one can check if the application was correctly built for OS X 10.5 by running 'otool':

otool -l binary

The correct binary should not contain any  'LC_DYLD_INFO_ONLY' load commands (only 'LC_DYLD_INFO' commands).

(also see my blog article http://grauonline.de/wordpress/?p=71 )